# Learn about the underlying principles of protocol compilers?

Tags: parsing, network-programming, protocols, finite-automata, state-machine

Can anyone recomend a really good book about protocol compilers, ie. how to generate protocol code?  I don't want any superficial book that sort of works like a cook book with a few recipies in it, instead I want to learn the fundamentals.  What should I study in order to grasp the subject of two or more finite state machines sending messages to each other with the possibility of messages not arriving or arriving out of order?  The question is "wide" as it were so any answer addressing the same general subject would be interesting.

Comment: Look at SPIN. No a book, but a tool (very well documented). Basically used for logic verification http://spinroot.com/spin/whatispin.html#A

Comment: @belisarius - Not quite sure if SPIN is what he is looking for. SPIN is a model checker, and does not really have anything to do with protocol compilation. I think he was only using the message passing as an example.

Comment: @Nico You are right. Perhaps the Austin protocol compiler book http://books.google.com/books?id=P4vmo2Sdjg8C is better suited. But I think a formal verification is due first, and then may be used as a backend for the compiler. Without verifying your protocol, you may get a running state machine bug :)